# Unable to parse text file in blocks using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have input file which contents info like below

```
DatastoreName      : vvc_prod_maid_hs01_5-New
RemotePath         : /vvc_prod_maid_hs01_5
RemoteHost         : 10.194.104.172
VM                 : bashkar
UsedSpaceGB        : 28.2
ProvisionedSpaceGB : 208.2
OwnerFolder        :

 

DatastoreName      : maid_vcs_prod_03
RemotePath         : /maid_vcs_prod_03
RemoteHost         : napmaidcp207v
VM                 : MAID01PUPVVC01
UsedSpaceGB        : 162.1
ProvisionedSpaceGB : 1049
OwnerFolder        :
```

I would like this column format like
DatastoreName      RemotePath            RemoteHost VM UsedspaceGB ProvisionSpacegb Ownerfolder

So far i tried and no Luck

```
$pattern = 'OwnerFolder        :'  
$content = Get-Content c:\anil\Scripts\manayata_data_store_list.txt | Out-String

$content.Split($pattern,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | ForEach-Object {

$item = $_ -split "\s+`n" | Where-Object {$_}

    New-Object PSobject -Property @{
        DatastoreName =$item[0].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        RemotePath = $item[1].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        RemoteHost=$item[2].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        VM =$item[3].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        UsedSpaceGB = $item[4].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        ProvisionedSpaceGB=$item[5].Split(':')[1].Trim()
        
    } | Select-Object DatastoreName,RemotePath,RemoteHost,VM,UsedSpaceGB ,ProvisionedSpaceG
    
}
```

Comment: This may help you: [Weltner Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU) ... you may watch it 'till the end!! ;-)

Comment: Have you considered exporting the data in a structured format such as Csv in the first place to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 2):

if you split the content based on the blank lines between them, you can replace the colons for `=`'s and let `ConvertFrom-StringData` do the conversion for you.

```
(Get-Content c:\anil\Scripts\manayata_data_store_list.txt -Raw) -split '(?<=\r?\n)\s+' | % {
    [PSCustomObject]($_ -replace ':','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData) 
}
```

Comment: Script was given to me , can you make changes in original script and let me know.

Comment: Presumably you will need to start a new object whenever a blank line occurs, otherwise this will result in dupplicate keys.